# When templating on typename T, what does T() mean?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

Here is my assignment for C++ course.  Certainly I will finish it by myself.  But there is a place I really have no ideas about.  Hope someone can explain that to me.  Thanks in advance.

The requirement of this assignment is like this:

We need to use template to create a customized class named **Set** to realize  the functionality of union (using operator `+`) and intersection (using operator `*`).  For example，`{4,2,3}+{9,4,8,2}` will be {8,3,9,2,4} and `{3,2,4}*{8,4,9,2}` will be {4,2}

Here is the skeleton of the xxxx.h file:

[xxxx.h file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSOBO.jpg)

Here is the code, but it can't display the red rectangle as the pic does.  But it is more readable: )

```
#ifndef A2P2_H
#define A2P2_H
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//========part a-Comments here:

//========part b-author's details
void info(){/* missing code */}

//========part c-exception classes:
class RemoveFromEmpty : exception{
    public:
        RemoveFromEmpty(){/* missing code */}
        const char* what() const noexcept {/* missing code */}
    private:
        string mMessage;
};

class NonExistingElem:exception{
    /* to be thrown when the element to be removed is not found in
    the set --------code missing */
};


//========part d-Set class template
template <typename EType>
class Set{
    public:
        //constructors
        Set( );
        Set( const Set & rhs );
        Set( Set && rhs );

        //destructor
        ~Set( );

        //operators overloaded
        Set & operator=( const Set & rhs );
        Set & operator=( Set && rhs );
        Set operator+( const Set & rhs ) const; //set union
        Set operator*( const Set & rhs ) const; //set intersection

        //methods
        bool isElement( const EType & x ) const;
        bool isEmpty( ) const;
        int getSize( ) const;

        //display on out all elements in the set between {..}
        void print( ostream & out = cout ) const;
        void setToEmptySet( );

        //methods to work with individual elements of a set
        void insert( const EType & x );
        void remove( const EType & x );

    private:
        struct Node{// type of the elements of the set
            EType mData;
            Node *mNext;
            Node( const EType & d = EType( ), Node *n = nullptr )
            : mData( d ), mNext( n ) { }
        };
        Node *mFirst;
        int mSize; // to have an efficient getSize().
};

//Write the definitions of all Set function members here:
//========part e-the output operator:
template <typename EType>
ostream & operator<< /* code missing here */
#endif
```

See the picture above and pay more attention to the highlighted part.  At the lower part, there is a red rectangle and the content is `const EType &d = EType()`.  I know EType is the type that I have declared in the template.  But what is `EType()`?  It's a function?

There is no other things related with `EType()` (i.e. some implementations for that function maybe) in the rest part of the requirement.  Actually, the left part is xxxx.cpp file and a result when executing that code.  I also post the them here if it would be helpful.

[xxxx.cpp and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgj7T.jpg)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a2p2.h"
using namespace std;

//It works only for sets of integers
template <typename T = int>
void testCopyCtr(Set<T> st){
    cout<< func <<": ";
    st.insert(23); //because of this statement
    st.print();
    cout<<endl;
}

int main( ){
    info(); //authors details
    try{
        Set<int> s1, s2;
        s1.insert( 8 );
        s1.insert( 3 );
        s1.insert( 1 );
        s1.insert( 4 );
        s1.insert( 1 );
        s1.remove( 8 );
        s1.insert( 2 );
        s2.insert( 4 );
        s2.insert( 2 );
        s2.insert( 6 );
        cout << "S1: " << s1 << ", size= " << s1.getSize( ) << endl;
        cout << "S2: " << s2 << ", size= " << s2.getSize( ) << endl;
        Set<int> s3 = s1+ s2; //union
        Set<int> s4 = s1* s2; //intersection
        cout << "s1 + s2: " << s3 << endl;
        cout << "s1 * s2: " << s4 << endl;
        Set<int> s5 = s4 = s3 = s2 = s1 = s1;
        cout << "S1: " << s1 << ", size= " << s1.getSize( ) << endl;
        cout << "S2: " << s2 << ", size= " << s2.getSize( ) << endl;
        cout << "S3: " << s3 << ", size= " << s3.getSize( ) << endl;
        cout << "S4: " << s4 << ", size= " << s4.getSize( ) << endl;
        cout << "S5: " << s5 << ", size= " << s5.getSize( ) << endl;
        cout << "S4 again : " << s4 << endl;
        testCopyCtr(s4);

        Set<float> sf;
        sf.remove(3);
    }
    catch(RemoveFromEmpty ex) {
        cout<<endl<<ex.what()<<endl;
        cout<<"Nothing to be done\n";
    }
    catch(NonExistingElem ex) {
        cout<<endl<<ex.what()<<endl;
        cout<<"Nothing to be done\n";
    }

    cout<<"All is well when it ends well!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience that result can only display in the picture.

Comment: For any constructable type `T`, the expression `T()` creates a temporary default-constructed or value-initialized object or instance of that type.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.  I think the code is maybe too long.  But yes, I just made up the code here.  That's more readable.  Thanks!

Comment: Jerry, you should consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Alternative syntax: `EType{ }`. Older books may not have this form yet.

Comment: Thanks buddy @Someprogrammerdude.  It's a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an invocation of a constructor. You are assigning a default-constructed `EType` value to variable `d` as `d`'s default value.

Comment: Technically not assignment (doesn't involve `EType::operator=`). `d` is a reference, and it's bound to an unnamed default-constructed `EType` object.

Comment: Thanks all guys for guiding me out of the trouble.